# Different languages for one country instance on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, permalinks, wpml, polylang

I have very specific question.
We need to create multilangual site on Wordpress with the custom permalink structure. It should be like that:
`/ - homepage /es-es/ - Spain and Spanish language /es-en/ - Spain and English language`
etc

But none of WP multilangual plugins can do such job and currently I can't even imagine how to solve that. Is it even possible? If yes, what solution do we need to use for that?

PS
I know, that we can use different WP-instances on subdomain, I know, that Polylang and WPML can't create such permalink structure. But I'm asking exactly if we can fo it exactly that way

I've tried to use Polylang and WPML, but they don't solve that issue. Also checked about multisite, but it doesn't match also

Comment: Can you use URLs like `example.com/es/` and `example.com/en/` with two-letter language codes? WPML [does that correctly](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/language-url-options/#different-languages-in-directories).

Comment: Yes, I know. But probably I didn't explain it well in the main question.
For example, we have Spanish version of the site. But we want to have two versions of the page EXACTLY for the spanish version. For example:
`/es-es/page`
`/es-en/page`
And all it should be inside the one website and the same for all of the languages. Like [here](https://stripe.com/)

I worked with WMPL and Polylang, but never have seen such functionality there

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a custom language](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/editing-wpmls-languages-table/#adding-your-own-languages-using-wpmls-gui) and then just copy content from `es-es` to `es-en` or use the [duplicate content](https://wpml.org/documentation/translating-your-contents/displaying-untranslated-content-on-pages-in-secondary-languages/) feature.